# Cucumber Reporting getting Error

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am using a Cucumber [reporting api](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting) for better reporting. My project is not a maven project and cannot change the project structure now. So I add all the dependency on my project but still now it is getting error like **"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File 'target/cucumber.json' does not contan features!"**

All added jars and version showing below.

[image]

I also added my runner class here which may help for debugging.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = { 
                "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                "json:target/cucumber.json"
        },features ={"./sample.feature"},
            glue ={"com/automation/steps"},strict = true,
            dryRun= false,monochrome = true, snippets= SnippetType.CAMELCASE)
/*public class Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
}*/
public class Runner {
    @AfterClass
     public static void generateReport(){
        File reportOutputDirectory = new File("target");
        List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        jsonFiles.add("target/cucumber.json");

        String jenkinsBasePath = "";
        String buildNumber = "1";
        String projectName = "cucumber-jvm";
        boolean skippedFails = true;
        boolean pendingFails = false;
        boolean undefinedFails = true;
        boolean missingFails = true;
        boolean runWithJenkins = false;
        boolean parallelTesting = false;

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, projectName);
        // optionally only if you need
        configuration.setStatusFlags(skippedFails, pendingFails, undefinedFails, missingFails);
        configuration.setParallelTesting(parallelTesting);
        configuration.setJenkinsBasePath(jenkinsBasePath);
        configuration.setRunWithJenkins(runWithJenkins);
        configuration.setBuildNumber(buildNumber);

        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

I also attached the project structure image.
[image]

I observed that feature-overview.html was generated under the folder structure but it was corrupted when I opened this file it was showing this error on this file.

[image]
Can any one please help me on this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your cukes runner is not able to identify path to feature file..

Try giving full path of your feature file in feature option..like src/test/java/sample.feature

Comment: @ Sunder thanks for your comment.But json file is creating properly and also default cucumber html report generated.My feature file was not in src it was direct under the projects folder.

Comment: Your html file and json file will create for report..It doesn't matter..You need to give correct path to feature file

Comment: I tried this as you mentioned but it was still getting error like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: G:\...\CucumberTest\src\test\java\sample.feature".Error showing on JUnit report.

Comment: I also dig it up the error which one I got previously I update my question accordingly so you can please check.

Comment: By the look of it..It's clearly mentioned in the report that your test didn't run because cukes runner is not able to pin point the exact location of the feature file..

Comment: Json file and html file will be created even for the test failures..obviously any report should do it

Comment: Keep feature file in the same location as runner file and give .\sample.feature file in feature options

Comment: I already lock a bug with all the details on github: https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues/390 but unfortunately bug was closed :). But I am really thankful to you,cause you also try to generate this report for me :).

Comment: @ it is not solved but owner thinks it is not an issue from reporting application. Owner think that json file is corrupted

Comment: No, issue not resolved after copy the file into the runner class package and setting the path as ./sample.feature.

Comment: I already solve this issue and discuss this on my blog http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.in/